# Codeigniter - human_to_unix correct input format?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form, which includes a date field.

The date will be received in the `format dd-mm-yyyy (e.g. 08-11-2015)`.

I want to convert this to a unix timestamp before inserting into the database.

If possible, I would like to use `Codeigniter` functions rather than native PHP functions.

`Codeigniter` has the function:

```
human_to_unix($input)
```

The function does not accept a format string and I cannot find the correct format to use ( how will it now that `08-11-2015 is 8th March 2015` rather than `11th August 2015`??).

Thanks

Comment: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/codeigniter-30-dev/readthedocs/codeigniter-30-dev.pdf

Comment: what is your expected output??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `date_helper` in CodeIgniter won't accept dates in the format `dd-mm-yyyy`. You can use standard PHP (although you specified you would prefer CodeIgniter functions):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '08-11-2015');
echo $date->format('U');
```

Alternatively, you can [extend the helpers](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) that CodeIgniter provides.

Create a new file `application/helpers/MY_date_helper.php`:

```
<?php
function human_to_unix_alternative($datestr) { // change this to a suitable function name
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $datestr);
    return $date->format('U');
}
```

You can then use it in your code, just as you'd use `human_to_unix($input)`, e.g. `human_to_unix_alternative($input)`.

Answer (score 0):

U have to use date format like this to get

```
 human_to_unix -> YY-MM-DD HH:MM <space> meridian
```

**ex:**

```
$this->load->helper('date_helper'); 
human_to_unix("2015-12-03 03:28 PM");
```

**outputs:**

> 1449136680

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->helper('date');
$input = strtotime('08-11-2015');

$human = unix_to_human($input);
$unix = human_to_unix($human);
```

Output will be:
2015-11-08 12:00 AM